# 1-degree SOS proof refutes Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, sums-of-squares, proof-complexity

I am trying to understand Sums-of-Squares proof systems.
A degree $d$ Sums-of-Squares refutation for a set of polynomial equations $P = \{p_1(x) = 0, ..., p_m(x) = 0\}$ is defined as
$\sum_{i=1}^m g_i(x)p_i(x) = s(x) + 1$ for a some polynomials $g_i$ and a sums-of-squares polynomial $s$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m g_i(x)p_i(x)$ is of degree at most $d$. Is it true that a degree $1$ Sums-of-Squares refutation proves the infeasibility of a linear program? Then the polynomials in $P$ must all be linear, the polynomials $g_i$ are just constants, but I do not understand the role of $s$ then.

Comment: in linear programming, you either have equations with nonnegative variables (something you can control by squaring them), or inequalities - and for these you either need a more general Positivstellensatz, or you'd need to introduce nonnegative slack variables, getting back to the previous case.

Comment: certainly, in LP with equations and nonnegative variables it could be that the corresponding system of linear equations is infeasible even if you drop non-negativity of variables, but this is a boring special case.

Comment: it seems the latter case is indeed as you describe, may be refuted with $s=0$ and $g_i$ not all zero constants, but this is not a refutation for a general LP feasibility problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! So you are saying there is no form of a linear program like $Ax = b$ without constraining $x\geq0$. So far I thought that restricting the polynomials $p_i$ to degree 1 yields a linear program, but thats not true then? Isnt it possible to introduce some slack variables to include $x\geq0$ in $Ax = b$?

Comment: No, you can't really get around nonnegativity by *linear* equations alone.

Comment: to comment on terminology - linear program (LP) is an optimisation problem, optimising a linear function on a polyhedron. Here we only talk about feasibility of an LP, e.g. non-emptiness of the polyhedron. Only if the polyhedron is an (affine) subspace you can avoid inequalities.